# MVC how to store user searches so user can go back

Tags: c#, angularjs, model-view-controller

Is such a thing possible? I have a search page and the user clicks a link to edit a document and it takes them to another page.

The user then hits the browser's back button i want to take them back to the results that they left off on so they don't have to search again.

EDIT: The search works as the user enters in parameters and it goes out to the database and returns results in a type of search result viewmodel. That viewmodel is parsed out to a table format and shown on the screen. Each row has certain bits of information tied to it like the primary key and other things that the user can see.

Once the user hits edit it uses the primary key to go back to the database to get the remaining data for that row and shows them a form on screen. If the user hits the back button on the browser I want to take them back to the result set that they just viewed without having to redo the search.

The way we have it setup is when the user hits back it goes to the index method that just does a new search page.

Comment: Your using angular, get rid of the back button and you should be good. Oh wait...

Comment: That isn't an option

Comment: @TerranceJackson Have a look at the html5 history API. It's meant to do exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the [HTML5 History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API). For instance, when the search returns its result you can use:

```
history.replaceState(..);
```

to modify the current browser history entry. It isn't compatible with some older browsers though, so if you have to support those, this may not work properly - or you'll have to find a workaround.

There exists a couple of 3rd party angular modules out there that wraps the history API, but it should work just fine on it's own.

Answer (score 0):

A way I've done this is by using a controller extension method to get the page's search state from session. I'm sure there is a better way to do this in Angular though.